# Django Bulk Update to Trigger save()

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I need to re-save all my models

> Users.objects.all().update(active=True)

In the model:

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url = "XYZ"

        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, the above does not trigger the `save()` method on these model. So no url = XYZ is set. Is this possible?

Update:

Looks like I cannot do this using .update() I have tried this:

```
>>> objects = Users.objects.all()
>>> for item in objects:
...     item.save()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about the motivation? Describe the use case. Thanks.

Comment: Methinks whatever OP is trying to do could be done more efficiently with a database trigger.

Comment: @alecxe Sure, I override the model Save() method with my own. This just at the point of saving adds some additional stuff to the DB. It appears that running the above command does not trigger the models Save() method.

Comment: @Kevin updated the OP to reflect what I want to do.

Comment: If catavaran's solution is not efficient enough for you, you can set a trigger on the SQL side to set the URL automatically.  The precise syntax will depend on your SQL backend (e.g. MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is [impossible](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#update):

> Realize that update() does an update at the SQL level and, thus, does not call any save() methods on your models, nor does it emit the pre_save or post_save signals (which are a consequence of calling Model.save()). If you want to update a bunch of records for a model that has a custom save() method, loop over them and call save()

```
$ ./manage.py shell
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> for u in User.objects.all():
...     u.is_active = True
...     u.save()
... 
>>>
```

Comment: I see, so I need to loop over each object and save within Django? Can this be done in the shell?